Django - Adding more options to AdminTimeWidget
I tried to add more time choices to AdminTimeWidget by overriding DateTimeShortcuts refering to this post also another similar posts on SO. My problems is I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTimeShortcuts is not defined and jQuery.Deferred exception: DateTimeShortcuts is not defined ReferenceError: DateTimeShortcuts is not defined at HTMLDocument error on console. I am newbie to django, I did not understant why I am getting this error. Here is how I implemented it:
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_ = [
            ['16:30', 16.5],
            ['17:30', 17.5],
            ['18:00', 18],
            ['19:00', 19],
            ['20:00', 20],
        ];

        DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink = function (num, val) {
            let d;
            if (val == -1) {
                d = DateTimeShortcuts.now();
            } else {
                const h = val | 0;
                const m = (val - h) * 60;
                d = new Date(1970, 1, 1, h, m, 0, 0);
            }
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].value = d.strftime(get_format('TIME_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]);
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].focus();
            DateTimeShortcuts.dismissClock(num);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);

and in my ModelAdmin I included this JS file in Media class as below:
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyAdminModel():
   // other stuff
   list_filter = [("created", custom_titled_datetime_range_filter("By created"))]

   class Media:
        js = ("admin/js/DateTimeShortcuts.js",)

Also I have a custom datetime range filter implemented as:
def custom_titled_datetime_range_filter(title):
    class CustomDateTimeRangeFilter(DateTimeRangeFilter):
        def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
            super().__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)
            self.title = title

    return CustomDateTimeRangeFilter


After looking through source code of DateTimeShortcuts, I have to include calendar.js and DateTimeShortcuts.js in my model admin as Media. Here is how I extended options:
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // push your custom options to `_default`
        DateTimeShortcuts.clockHours.default_.push([gettext_noop('3:30 p.m.'), 15.5]);

        DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink = function (num, val) {
            let d;
            if (val == -1) {
                d = DateTimeShortcuts.now();
            } else {
                const h = val | 0;
                const m = (val - h) * 60;
                d = new Date(1970, 1, 1, h, m, 0, 0);
            }
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].value = d.strftime(get_format('TIME_INPUT_FORMATS')[0]);
            DateTimeShortcuts.clockInputs[num].focus();
            DateTimeShortcuts.dismissClock(num);
        };
    });
})(django.jQuery);

and in Model Admin inlcude these files:
@admin.register(models.MyModel)
class MyAdminModel():

   class Media:
        js = (
            "admin/js/calendar.js",
            "admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js",
            "admin/js/time-shortcuts.js",
        )


Now all dependency files will load in order and time-shortcuts.js will override the options.
